# OpenId Blazor refresh_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, blazor, openid, refresh-token

I have a desktop client application that uses Azure AD to authenticate users.
I wish to use the same authentication already provided by the user in the client application and pass the token to a new Blazor project. So if i pass the refresh_token as a queryparameter to my new web application can i use it to genreate new access tokens for that user without the need for them to re authenticate?

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot use a refresh token on a SPA application and Blazor is a SPA. Because there isn't secured way to store the refresh token on a browser.
However, you can renew the access token. Actually the access token is automatically renewed using the same mechanism oidc.js use (by using an iframe).
You must configure your client with the authorization code flow with PKCE (or implicit flow, but it's deprecated)